# One websocket connection for all content scripts in a chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, websocket

Is there a way to achieve having only and only one websocket connection for all content scripts in your chrome-extension?

Since content scripts can not use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages , there is no way as far as i know.

why only one websocket connection? Because, opening a websocket connection is relatively expensive process especially if you have do it again and again many times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand you but I think this is solution:

1. Open websocket in the background page.
2. Create [Port](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) connection between background page and content script.
3. Send and receive JSON massages through Port and websocket

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, i tried something similar but i guess the problem was about loading an extension page( with jquery's load function ) and then calling content script inside it :) Now i realize it ... i'll try this approach again with a proper implementation.

Comment: what do you mean by "Port connection"? I have a websocket instantiated in my background script, but it doesn't always load. If I refresh the page, it doesn't connect. Sometimes it will though. I have no idea if the background.js is loaded once at chrome startup or what. i need to instantiate when my content_scripts load, but in the background.js

Comment: @chovy background page starts once when Chrome starts and it runs indefinitely in (surprise!) the background. When Chrome visits a page it checks all the manifests what content scripts should be run. Content scripts can perform many actions during execution i.e. connect to their background pages. Port is a connection between content script and its background page - they cannot communicate directly because they are executed in different contexts.